# How does h2o.stackedensemble() compare the training frames used by the base models?

Tags: java, h2o, ensemble-learning

I observed something interesting when using h2o.stackedensemble() to build ensembles.

The training frame was a data frame in R and I imported it into h2o first:

df.h2o = as.h2o(df, destination_frame='df.h2o)

then I used df.h2o to build a glm.

Later I ran the importing command (df.h2o = as.h2o(df, destination_frame='df.h2o)) again accidentally and used df.h2o to build a boosting model.

Although these two models were built with the same seed, cross-validation folds and actually the same training frame, it turned out that I could not blend them using h2o.stackedensemble(); it returned an error message "Error: java.lang.NullPointerException". I did some trouble shooting and the conclusion was that because I imported the same data frame twice, h2o believed that the two base models were built using different training frames.

Could anyone tell me how h2o.stackedensemble() compares the training frames used by base models? Does it actually check the content of the training frames or just use some ids generated internally when the frames were created? When there are lots of base models, it is quite common that they have to be built, saved and reloaded in different sessions, making the scenario described above inevitable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The null pointer exception was caused by a bug, which has now been fixed on master.  So if you want that fix immediately, you can install the nightly build from [here](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/latest.html), or you can wait for the next [stable release](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable.html) (in the next week or two).  If that doesn't fix your issue, please post back here.

We had some additional checks on the training frames of the base learners that were too strict and we are going to further relax those restrictions (they were originally put in to prevent the user from accidentially mixing base models that are not compatible for stacking), but we are going to further loosen the restrictions.  You can follow the progress in this [JIRA](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-6035).

Comment: Thank you very much Erin! Exciting to see what h2o has achieved so far!